# Thorntail/swarm : cannot use XAdatasources?

Tags: java, datasource, xa, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I use Thorntail 2.2.0 (BOM), inserted the fraction datasource and had a project-defaut.yml set :

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    xa-data-sources:
      statsDS:
        driver-name: postgresql
        jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/statsDS
        user-name: stats
        password: stats++
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter
        xa-datasource-properties:
          URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres4stats:5432/stats

      oracleDS:
        driver-name: oracle
        jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/oracleDS
        user-name: ora
        password: ora++
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: true
        background-validation: false
        stale-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter
        xa-datasource-properties:
          URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE

    jdbc-drivers:
      oracle:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        xa-datasource-class: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
        driver-module-name: com.oracle
      postgresql:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        xa-datasource-class: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

In `Resources/modules/com/oracle/main`, I have a module.xml file and same with postgresql in the right directory (`org/postgresql/main`).

Everything seems to load ok, no error so far when I launch my uber-jar. I can see `INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/statsDS]` and the same with oracle.
And later on in logs : `(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Thorntail 2.2.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 3390ms - Started 221 of 413 services (256 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)`

Up to this I'm happy ... but ...

As far as I understand, after the boot controler had started, swarm begins to load my War. Every thing runs ok until it tries to create a connection :

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) statsDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@3ce4c9a9[userName=stats]) [0/20]
2018-10-01 12:26:21,025 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) oracleDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@1427a5a3[userName=ora]) [0/20]
2018-10-01 12:26:21,026 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:416)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1327)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:875)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031101: XADataSourceClass is undefined
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:621)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:493)
    ... 35 more
```

Unable to create a connection ; xadatasourceclass undefined ... 
I don't see what I did wrong ; and google neither !

So, if you have any idea, please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2.2.0.Final/#_datasources you need to set the XA DataSource Driver Class like below:

```
jdbc-drivers:
  oracle:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    driver-xa-datasource-class-name: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
    driver-module-name: com.oracle
  postgresql:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    driver-xa-datasource-class-name: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
    driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

Comment: As I said to @Clément Bareth, I did so, and I made some progress. But for postgres I have an NPE :  ```at org.postgresql.PGProperty.get(PGProperty.java:490)
 at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.setUrl(BaseDataSource.java:1113)``` and with oracle ```ÙRL not valid```. As if it can't read URL connection ...

Answer (score 0):

According from Thortnail documentation : http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2.0.0.Final/#_datasources.

Maybe you should also define the xa-datasource-class in the datasources definitions.

And change driver-class-name by driver-xa-datasource-class-name.

**Edit** : The solution that finally worked was to use an XML configuration file for datasources configuration.

On my side, I noted that YML configuration files was leading to some bugs when it came to overwrite existing default properties of swarm.

Comment: Yes I saw this and I tried, but I got  ```2018-10-01 14:17:11,186 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) statsDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@429f885c[userName=stats]) [0/20]
[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) oracleDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@34bb08a6[userName=ora]) [0/20]
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) JDBC URL must start with "jdbc:postgresql:" but was: undefined```

Comment: Did you try to set "swarm.datasources.xa-data-sources.KEY.url-property" instead of xa-datasource-properties.URL" ?

Comment: What I personally did on my installation is to use old XML configuration for datasource and set "ServerName", "PortNumber" and "DatabaseName" xa-datasource-properties. Maybe you could give a try to those properties in "xa-datasource-properties" section

Comment: Like this ?       `xa-datasource-properties:
          ServerName: postgres4stats
          PortNumber: 5432` Then I have a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined`
          DatabaseName: stats

Comment: Then maybe you can try with standalone.xml configuration file for the xa-datasources

Comment: Thank you Clément :) I finally used *-ds.xml files ; dropped project-default.yml and modify my pom.xml then it uses com.oracle.ojdbc7.12.1.0.2 (before it was com.oracle.ojdbc14.10.2.0.4.0).  And it worked :).  BTW, I had to set the timezone cause I had `ORA-01882: timezone region  not found`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you came across the same issue I ran into recently: [THORN-1281](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-1281)

Basically, what this means is that rather than doing

```
    xa-datasource-properties:
      URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE
```

you should write

```
    xa-datasource-properties:
      URL: 
        value: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE
```